# Clear Fragment Backstack immediately after transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` with a cancel button that sends people back to a 
a starting `Fragment`:

```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener{
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder,StartFragment.newInstance()).commit()
    }
```

I would like to clear the entire `Fragment` backstack when this starting `Fragment` is returned to. I am attempting to do this in the Fragment's onStart method:

```
 while (activity!!.supportFragmentManager!!.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStackImmediate()
        }
```

Doing this throws the common  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions` error when the cancel button is pressed, but even after reading about other people's problems, I still can't figure out how these transactions work and what is happening to cause this error. The fragments are contained within a FrameLayout.

Comment: Well, don't do it in the Fragment's onStart method, that's kinda weird.

Comment: Okay, what's better?

Comment: I would think you should do that before you add this fragment with the commit().

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after replace and before commit, do the pop operation and it should work.

Comment: It did. Thank you.